# Ignition Gazebo Pose Publisher unexpected behaviour

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-ignition, ignition-fortress, gazebo-plugins

Good afternoon to everyone. I have the following problem:
I'm running a simulation with one turtlebot that is able to move simple objects in a rectangular arena. Both the arena and the objects are defined in sdf format.
This is the code for the objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
 <sdf version="1.9">

    <model name ="object">
        
        
        <link name="link_object">

            <visual name="visual_object">                   
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder>
                        <radius>.1</radius>
                        <length>0.08</length>
                    </cylinder>
                </geometry>
                <material>
                    <diffuse>1 1 0 1</diffuse>
                </material>
            </visual>

            <collision name="collision_object">
                <geometry>
                    <cylinder>
                        <radius>.1</radius>
                        <length>0.08</length>
                    </cylinder>
                </geometry>

                <surface>
                    <friction>
                        <ode>
                            <mu>0.05</mu>
                        </ode>
                    </friction>
                </surface>

            </collision>

        </link>
    </model>
    

</sdf>`
```

And this is the code to build the arena:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.9">
    <world name="arena">

    <scene>
        <ambient>1 1 1 1</ambient>
        <grid>0</grid>
    </scene>


    <physics type="ode">
        <max_step_size>0.003</max_step_size>
        <real_time_factor>1.0</real_time_factor>
    </physics>


    <gazebo>
        <plugin file_name="libignition-gazebo-contact-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Contact"/>
    </gazebo>
    <gazebo>
        <plugin file_name="libignition-gazebo-sensors-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
            <render_engine>ogre</render_engine>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>

    <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::Physics' filename='libignition-gazebo-physics-system.so'/>
        <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::UserCommands' filename='libignition-gazebo-user-commands-system.so'/>
        <plugin name='ignition::gazebo::systems::SceneBroadcaster' filename='libignition-gazebo-scene-broadcaster-system.so'/>

        <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-contact-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Contact"></plugin>

        <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-sensors-system.so" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::Sensors">
            <render_engine>ogre</render_engine>
    </plugin>



    <light type="point" name="point_light1">
        <intensity>1</intensity>
        <pose>0 -0.6 1.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <diffuse>1 1 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>.1 .1 .1 1</specular>
        <attenuation>
          <range>4</range>
          <linear>1</linear>
          <constant>0.8</constant>
          <quadratic>0</quadratic>
        </attenuation>
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
    </light>

    <light type="point" name="point_light2">
        <intensity>1</intensity>
        <pose>1.5 -0.6 1.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <diffuse>1 1 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>.1 .1 .1 1</specular>
        <attenuation>
          <range>4</range>
          <linear>1</linear>
          <constant>0.8</constant>
          <quadratic>0</quadratic>
        </attenuation>
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
    </light>


    <light type="point" name="point_light3">
        <intensity>1</intensity>
        <pose>-1.5 -0.6 1.5 0 0 0</pose>
        <diffuse>1 1 0 1</diffuse>
        <specular>.1 .1 .1 1</specular>
        <attenuation>
          <range>4</range>
          <linear>1</linear>
          <constant>0.8</constant>
          <quadratic>0</quadratic>
        </attenuation>
        <cast_shadows>false</cast_shadows>
    </light>


    <include>
        <uri>ground.sdf</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
        <uri>walls.sdf</uri>
    </include>
    
    <model name="objects">


        <!-- include objects-->

        <include>
            <uri>object.sdf</uri>
            <name>object1</name>
            <pose>0.4 0.1 1 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>
        
        <include>
            <uri>object.sdf</uri>
            <name>object2</name>
            <pose>-0.4 0.8 1 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>

        <include>
            <uri>object.sdf</uri>
            <name>object3</name>
            <pose>1.3 0.8 1 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>

        <include>
            <uri>object.sdf</uri>
            <name>object4</name>
            <pose>-1.3 0.8 1 0 0 0</pose>
        </include>

        <plugin filename="libignition-gazebo-pose-publisher-system" name="ignition::gazebo::systems::PosePublisher">
            <publish_link_pose>false</publish_link_pose>
            <publish_model_pose>false</publish_model_pose>
            <publish_nested_model_pose>false</publish_nested_model_pose>
            <use_pose_vector_msg>true</use_pose_vector_msg>
        </plugin>

    </model>


</world>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I try to push an object with the turtlbot the pose on the corresponding topic is updated with the right value only for the objects 2,3,4. If I move the object 1 the values of all the other objects are being updated, except the pose for the object 1.
I think there must be a problem on the PosePublisher plugin but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.